# Is there any reference for renderscript?

Tags: android, renderscript

I am new to RenderScript and I want to take advantage of the high performance of parallel computing of the RenderScript. But all I can find on Internet are some samples and blogs. Is there any manual I can learn the grammar things from?

Comment: If you use intellj idea then you have to use gradle project because the ant version doesn't support it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RenderScript**

- [API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html)
- [API Reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/reference.html)
- [Support library v8](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v8)

Apart from guides and blog posts that you already mentioned, there are a few other resources which you might find useful:

- [Official samples](http://developer.android.com/samples/renderscript.html)
- [Google I/O 2013 RenderScript talk](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/331954522)
- [Android Developers Backstage Podcast on RenderScript](http://androidbackstage.blogspot.com/2014/02/android-developers-backstage-episode-5.html)